# I need my script to cycle through 3 corresponding arrays

Tags: python

Okay, this is going to need a little bit of explanation...

I'm making a reddit bot with praw, and I am storing topics, descriptions for the topic, and the user who submitted the top in a variable via an array.

Each week, the bot will post a new reddit thread which should contain 1 topic, and it's respective description and submitter.

What I need the script to do is cycle through the arrays without repeating any of the data, so that I don't get any repeat posts.

The bot will be on a scheduler that runs it every week, which is the part that is tripping me up, since normal methods won't permanently clear the options.

Optimally, I would want to store the code in another variable for each data type that I could use to put in the preset messages

Here's the variables:

```
#Question Databank
challengeTopicData = ('Command line', 'Choose your own theme', 'Memes', 'Glitch','No app drawer','Not minimal')
challengeDescriptionData = ('The best command-line/vintage computer theme','Choose a theme from given pool of choices and they will have to stick to it completely.','Make a theme from a meme. It\'s literally wide open - make the crappiest, low effort theme you can for 1 week only','Create a theme based around a glitch effect, whether it be the wallpaper, widget, or both','In this challenge you must create a homescreen with all of your icons on it, and show off your homescreen organization skills','Literally anything that can\'t be considered minimal')
challengeSubmitterData = ('-Tilde','thetinygoat','SuperScientistOfDoom','hallowaslosdu','inaforestgump','ssyynnxx')
```

Comment: I don't see any arrays, only tuples. And what's the question again?

Comment: I don't see any code either... just 3 variables...

Comment: @AndrasDeak Sorry, I meant tuples. If I need to change them to arrays for something to work, then I could do that too.

The original question is that each time I run it I need a new item chosen from those variables, and they have to correspond to each other

Comment: Do you need post-level uniqueness, or post component level uniqueness? That is, if you post components, A, B and C in week 1, can week 2's post be components X, B and Z, where B is the same as week 1? Or are the values linked, so you're selecting matched elements in each `tuple`?

Comment: I would recommend instead of having 3 arrays, create a list of dicts instead. Each dict can have keys of topics, description and user with respective values. Will make your life easier. Or maybe just a list of tuples instead.

Comment: @HunkDivine I was thinking that it might be the way to go, but the python docs acted like it had to be a string and a number. Can you possibly elaborate and give me an example in my use case?

Comment: @ShadowRanger In my example, Command line, The best command-line....., and -Tilde should all be selected

Comment: It sounds like you need to store the list index in a file. Every time the script runs, it reads the file, increments the index, gets that element of the list, and writes the new index to the file.

Comment: @AlexBracken redditDict = [{'topic':'random topic 1', 'description':'random description 1', 'user': 'random user 1'}, {'topic':'random topic 2', 'description':'random description 2', 'user': 'random user 2'}]

Similarly, instead of the dicts, you can have tuple directly with values like [('random topic 1', 'random desc 1', 'random user 1'), ('random topic 2', 'random desc 2', 'random user 2')]

Comment: @Barmar Can you give me instructions on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: @AlexBracken Which part of it is confusing you? They're all pretty simple steps.

Comment: @HunkDivine That makes a little more sense, but how would I go about choosing a different dict each time?

Comment: As @Barmar mentioned, an number in a file somewhere. read a number from a file. use at as the index for the list and you have your three things. Also update your number in the file. Make sure to reset the number if it reaches the end of the list.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that it may be simple to you, but I don't even know where to begin, so in my eyes that answer was vague and not helpful in and of itself

Comment: Just take it step by step. Do you know how to open a file and read the contents? Do you know how to convert a string to a number? Do you know how to add 1 to a number? Do you know how to use a number as the index into a list or tuple? Do you know how to write a number to a file?

Comment: I don't know how I can be more helpful without actually writing the script for you. Each of those steps is just 1 or two lines of Python code.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, well as a testament to my knowledge (or lack thereof), the only thing on that list I am confident I can do is add 1 to a number. I'm not sure how much more helpful you can be either without writing a script unless you would like to baby me through it

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service. You need to read a tutorial that explains how to use files from Python.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for getting me started at least @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Some thing along these lines, you can change your data to dicts or tuples however you like.

```
def example():
    f1 = open("count.txt","r+")
    index = int(f1.read())
    data = [{'topic':'random topic 1', 'description':'random description 1', 'user': 'random user 1'}, {'topic':'random topic 2', 'description':'random description 2', 'user': 'random user 2'}]

    f1.seek(0,0)
    f1.write("%s" % index+1)
    f1.close()
    return data[index]
```

Comment: What would count.txt need to look like?

Comment: just a number, create it and put a 0 in it to start

Comment: Okay, I've got that done. Now how do I reference the data in a variable?

Comment: the function returns a dict, you can get the things inside like >>>result = example() >>> result["topic"] >>> result["description"]

You probably want to structure the function in a different way according to your other reddit code.

Comment: One last thing: whenever i run it, it says, "TypeError: must be str, not int"

Comment: @AlexBracken change f1.write("%s" % index+1) to f1.write("%s" % str(index+1)) . Also make sure to accept the answer if it works.